# Avoid syncing certain parts of a model

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs-mvc

Let's say I have a Sencha Touch model like this:

```
Ext.regModel('User', {
    'fields': [{
        'name': 'first_name',
        'type': 'string'
     }, {
        'name': 'last_name',
        'type': 'string'
     }, {
        'name': 'full_name',
        'type': 'string',
        'convert': function(v, record) {
            return record.data.first_name + ' ' + record.data.last_name;
        }
     }, {
        'name': 'age',
        'type': 'integer'
     }
]});
```

The server returns the 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'age' fields when getting records. However, when I update a user's first and/or last name, and I call `sync()` on the store, it will send all fields to the server, including full_name and age, even though I don't want that.

I know I could just ignore that data on the server, but in some cases (with lots of fields with 'convert' for example) it adds lots of unnecessary overhead to the payload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the config `persist: false` for the field?

**Edit** I guess you could create your own writer for the proxy and override the `getRecordData` method.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.NewWriter', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Writer',
    getRecordData: function(record) {
        return {
            first_name: record.data.first_name,
            last_name: record.data.last_name,
            age: record.data.age
        };
    }
});

...
proxy: {
    writer: Ext.create('Ext.ux.NewWriter');
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It seems to have no effect. Also, it's not listed in the [API docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.DataView) (though I couldn't find there any option I could use.)

Comment: i was looking at the api for extjs 4 :), where field has the configuration persist.. apparently not available in sencha

Comment: Oh, that's actually good news: at some point, it will be available. I'll see if I can backport it to Sencha Touch in the meantime.